# Update multiple MySQL records with one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I would like to update multiple MySQL records from the same table, using only one submit button.

Here is a simple version of the code that I am using to generate the form:

```
<form action='' method='post'> 
    <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT TagName, TagID FROM tags";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ($sql. '-error' .mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<input type='text' name='TagField' value='".$row['TagName']."'>";
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="tag_edit_submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

What sort of UPDATE query could I use? I can't seem to figure out the correct combination of arrays/loops to make it happen. Please let me know if you require more information.

Comment: First problem you would get just one TagField sent back change `TagField` to `TagField[]`. And show some code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can carry the tagIds with the tag names in the form. I assume tagIds count and tagNames count are identical.

```
<form action='' method='post'> 
    <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT TagName, TagID FROM tags";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ($sql. '-error' .mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='TagIDs[]' value='".$row['TagID']."'>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='TagNames[]' value='".$row['TagName']."'>";
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="tag_edit_submit" value="Edit">
</form>


<?php 
$p=$_POST;
if( isset($p['TagNames']) && is_array($p['TagNames'] )) {

  foreach($p['TagNames'] as $key=>$name){

    $tagId= $p['TagIds'][$key];

    // validate and clean up sql injections from $tagId and $name

    $sql='update tags set TagName="'.$name.'" where TagID=".$tagId." limit 1';
    // execute the query
  }

} 
?>
```